# Angular routing with absolute base href and modules

Tags: angular2-routing, angular6

We need to deploy Angular 6 sites on different IIS servers (dev/qa/prod/etc.). Routes are defined in modules:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'module1', loadChildren: './modules/module1#Module1' },
    { path: 'module2', loadChildren: './modules/module2#Module2' },
    { path: 'module3', loadChildren: './modules/module3#Module3' },
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'module1' },
];
```

Since the base path will be different on all servers, we used to set it as a relative url:

```
<base href="./">
```

IIS is configured to rewrite the urls to send to the index page in the proper subfolder.

```
<rule name="Angular Routes" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)/\b(module1|module2|module3)?(/.*)?" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/" />
</rule>
```

The rewriting works fine. I checked the resulting routes using an aspx page, and it works as expected.

The issue appear to be with the base href. If I write an absolute path, all the routes work fine. We can refresh the page and get redirected to the proper angular page. But if I use the relative './' path, it doesn't work in all cases.

https://server/test/2.0 => works fine (folder where index.html is located)

https://server/test/2.0/module1 => works fine

https://server/test/2.0/module1/page1 => doesn't work - base path is set to https://server/test/2.0/module1

Is there a way to use an relative path and still get all the routes to be resolved? I know I could use the hash strategy, but I was trying to get it working using the location strategy.

Thanks!

Comment: Create a custom compoent call it 'redirector' which has for role to redirect all `Module1/:page` to its appropriate path.